# Typescript compiler not finding .tsx files after switch to project relative paths in webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, atom-editor, tsconfig

I keep getting the error that my .tsx files are no longer within the typescript compilation context.  These errors started occuring after I defined root paths within my webpack configuration file and changed all of my import paths to be relative to those root paths.

I understand why the typescript compiler is complaining, because it doesn't know how to resolve the files.  I'm wondering if there is a configuration that I can put into my tsconfig.json that will make this work again?

webpack contains configuration that looks as follows:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.png', '.scss'],
    root: [
        path.resolve('./src'),
        path.resolve('./node_modules')
    ]
}
```

My tsconfig.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "files": [
    "index.d.ts",
    "./src/**/*.tsx",
    "./src/*.tsx",
    "./lib/**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

Adding this configuration to webpack allows me to have imports that are simplified, instead of '../../folder1/folder2/module' I can just specify 'folder1/folder2/module', however, if this means that I cannot leverage the tools within my IDE (Atom, VSCode) then this is a non-starter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if there is a configuration that I can put into my tsconfig.json that will make this work again

You can use the `rootDirs` option in TypeScript nightly : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#module-resolution-enhancements-baseurl-path-mapping-rootdirs-and-tracing

## More

I always recommend staying on nightly : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/getting-started.html#typescript-version